Draw directly on an image in Svelte
I have an application that presents images. I need to let the user to click the image and to mark the specific place where the user clicked.
Below listed a simple example of the current code. Clicking the image shows the relative coordinates of the click to image, i.e., as if the top-left corner of the image is the (0, 0).
<script lang="ts">
    const image = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/mturk/main/15545/frame_0.jpg`;

    let topLeftP = {x: 0, y: 0};
    let mouseClickP = {x: 0, y: 0};
    const imageDimensions = {w: 1280, h: 640};

    function handleMousemove(event){
        var videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName("image")[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        topLeftP.x = videoElement.left
        topLeftP.y = videoElement.top

        mouseClickP.x = event.clientX - topLeftP.x;
        mouseClickP.y = event.clientY - topLeftP.y;
        

    }


</script>

<main>
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events -->
    <img 
        id="imageCanvas"
        class="image"
        src={image} 
        alt='Blank' 
        on:click|preventDefault={(e)=>handleMousemove(e)}
    />
    <div>The mouse position is ({mouseClickP.x}, {mouseClickP.y})</div>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 240px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #ff3e00;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 4em;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px) {
        main {
            max-width: none;
        }
    }
</style>

I need to mark the point clicked with a red dot, so that it will be seen with a naked eye.
I saw this answer, but it uses a canvas which I could not understand how to make it work with an image, as I need the point to appear directly on the image itself.

You can use an HTML structure like this one:
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="the-image.jpeg" />
    <span class="marker"></span>
</div>

The idea is that:

.container is equally big as .image
.marker can be positioned anywhere within .container

To make (1) happen, use the following CSS:
.container{
   display: inline-block;
}

To make (2) happen, use the additional CSS:
 .container{
    /* This enables children to use position: absolute to be positioned using absolute coordinates relative to this element. */
    position: relative;
 }
.marker{
    
    /* Here we position this element relative to the .container element. */
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%; /* Update this using JS when the user clicks. */
    top: 75%; /* Update this using JS when the user clicks. */
    
    /* left and top indicates the position of the top left corner. You probably want it to be centered at that position. So translate (move it) 50% of it's size up and to the left. */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
    /* Make it look like a circle. */
    width: 50px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    
}


What remains if for you to write the JS to only show the .marker after the user has clicked the image, and to update it's left and top values.

Thanks @Peppe L-G for the answer. Where should I put these methods? In a <style> close? What is the right way to update the values? Thanks

I'm sorry, but I can't write all the code you need for a functional solution, only help you with the parts you're struggling with, which I interpreted as placing a marker at specific coordinates on the image. But the code I wrote you can place in its own Svelte component, and then add the missing JS code to it, and much of that you have yourself in your original question. To update left and top, you can use the style directive.

The marker does not appear on the image but below it. Is there a way to make to move it on the image?

It works for me. Update your question with the code you have. To move it, you need to use JS in Svelte. Listen for the click event on .container, and compute x and y coordinates of the click position relative to the .container's top left corner, and then convert that to percentage by using .container's width and height, and divide those by the click's x and y coordinates relative to .container respectively and multiplying them by 100.

This is a self-contained example. Could you please provide the same code but with the requred functionality? Thanks in advance
